# How to remove item from recyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I should use recyclerView and remove some items.
I want remove some items from `recyclerview` and for this I write below code in **Adapter** :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<TvTonightResult> model;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<TvTonightResult> model) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_tv_tonight, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tvTonightTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.get(position).getName()));
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .override(600, 900)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model,
                                                   Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.tvTonightImage);

        long time = 5 * 1000;
        holder.tvTonightTimeCounter.start(time);
        holder.tvTonightTimeCounter.setOnCountdownEndListener(new CountdownView.OnCountdownEndListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEnd(CountdownView cv) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView tvTonightImage, tvTonightChannel;
        private TextView tvTonightTitle, tvTonightDate;
        private CountdownView tvTonightTimeCounter;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvTonightImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tvTonightImage);
            tvTonightChannel = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tvTonightChannelImage);
            tvTonightTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tvTonightTitle);
            tvTonightTimeCounter = (CountdownView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tvTonightTime);

        }
    }

    private void removeItem(int position) {
        model.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, model.size());
    }
}
```

I want when run this code, **remove** item :

```
holder.tvTonightTimeCounter.setOnCountdownEndListener(new CountdownView.OnCountdownEndListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEnd(CountdownView cv) {
                    removeItem(position);
                }
            });
```

But show me this **error** :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 9711
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
    at com.example.app.Adapters.TvTonightAdapter.removeItem(TvTonightAdapter.java:102)
    at com.example.app.Adapters.TvTonightAdapter.access$300(MyAdapter.java:29)
    at com.example.app.Adapters.TvTonightAdapter$2.onEnd(MyAdapter.java:74)
    at com.example.app.Utils.Componenets.CountDownTimer.CountdownView$1.onFinish(CountdownView.java:129)
    at com.example.app.Utils.Componenets.CountDownTimer.CustomCountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CustomCountDownTimer.java:74)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

How can I fix this error and remove item from `recyclerview`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should call `remove(holder.getAdapterPosition())` instead of `remove(position)` because, when the holder's countdown finishes, it might have changed its position.

Suppose the following situation:

1º holder -> 5 seconds countdown

2º holder -> 10 seconds countdown

Since the second holder finishes after the first one, after 10 seconds,  `remove(1)` will be called but, since the first holder has already been removed, the second holder's position will be 0. Hence, it should call `remove(0)` instead of `remove(1)` (which will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`).

Comment: Thanks my friend, can you  send me full code with my above codes? because I am amateur, thanks my friend. please

Comment: Just replace `remove(position)` for `remove(holder.getAdapterPosition())` inside your `setOnCountDownEndListener`.

Comment: thanks.!!!  It solve my problem about the position of recyclerview in removing or updating

Answer (score 20):

just try ,

```
int actualPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

in your `removeItem()` method and replace position with `actualPosition`.

like ,

```
  private void removeItem(int position) {
    int actualPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    model.remove(actualPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(actualPosition);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(actualPosition, model.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but I want show just 4 item . not show all of items from server! I want show just 4 item

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove items if you want to display just 4 items just change get count method as below

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (model.size()>4)?4:model.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only four item if there are more than four item and exact number of item if there are less than four item. Then, you can use this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int count = 0;
    if (model != null && model.size() > 0) {
        int listSize = model.size();
        if (listSize > 4) {
            count = 4;
        } else {
            count = listSize;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//////// set the position ////////

holder.tvTonightTimeCounter.setTag(position);

//////// remove item from recyclerview and arraylist ///////

holder.tvTonightTimeCounter.setOnCountdownEndListener(new CountdownView.OnCountdownEndListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEnd(CountdownView cv) {
                    int positionToRemove = (int)view.getTag(); //get the position of view to delete stored in the tag
                    model.remove(positionToRemove);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```