# Remove clicked image from Glide RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I've looked quite a lot of places to see if I can find anything that lets me know how to remove an image from a **glide** created **RecyclerView** but I'm not finding anything. Almost all of the examples I've seen has dealt with **diskCacheStrategy** or something like that for Glide but does not describe how to remove an image from the RecyclerView.

My goal is that I just want to remove the image I click on in the list.

I populate the **RecyclerView** using this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    fbPhotos fbPhotos = mFbPhotos[position];
    ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

    Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(fbPhotos.getUrl())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
        .into(imageView);
}
```

And this is the code I use when detecting a click on any of those images:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mPhotoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            fbPhotos fbPhotos = mFbPhotos[position];
        }
    }
}
```

The full code:

```
public class frag_photos extends Fragment {
    public frag_photos() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private fbPhotos[] mFbPhotos;
    private Context mContext;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_photos, container, false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_images);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(getContext(), fbPhotos.getFBPhotos());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Getting SwipeContainerLayout
        swipeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

        //swip listener
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            Log.d("test", "regresh");
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private class ImageGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View photoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
            ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder(photoView);

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            fbPhotos fbPhotos = mFbPhotos[position];
            ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(fbPhotos.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (mFbPhotos.length);
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            public ImageView mPhotoImageView;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mPhotoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    fbPhotos fbPhotos = mFbPhotos[position];
                }
            }
        }

        public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context, List<fbPhotos> fbPhotos) {
            mContext = context;
            mFbPhotos = fbPhotos.toArray(new fbPhotos[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371534/how-to-remove-item-from-recyclerview-in-android) comes close to what I am looking to do but I just don't understand the OP code to get a clear view of what all is going on.

Help with this would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE 1**

So the suggested `notifyItemRemoved(position);` does remove the image from the list but it seems to just add a duplicate of the last image each time you click on an image?

[image]

Comment: In your onClick `notifyItemRemoved(position)` Then `mFbPhotos.remove(postion)` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Glide has nothing to do with this . You only need to call `notifyItemRemoved` with the position as mentioned in your given link .

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah Its saying **Cannot resolve method 'remove' in 'fbPhotos'** when trying to add that `mFbPhotos.remove(postion)`.

Comment: @ADM Updated my OP to show the effect of click on an image to remove.

Comment: @StealthRT After removing item using `notifyItemRemoved` did you removed that index from your arraylist too? it seems that you're not deleting that postion/index from arraylist

Comment: Instead of using `fbPhotos[]` you can use `ArrayList<fbPhotos>` it supports `remove` function

Comment: Use a Collection instead of Array because Size of Array is fixed . So use Array List Instead .. Then first remove Item from ArrayList then call notifyItemremove with same index . That should do it

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah Using `fbPhotos.getFBPhotos().remove(position);` does not seem to remove anything from the list?